# Why can I connect to svn from command line but not from tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using a sliksvn server and a tortoise client, both installed on my local machine. Today I moved my repository folder to another drive and reinstalled svnserve as a windows service with the new repository location.

From that time on I can only access a repository from command line using

```
svn list svn://localhost/Example
```

I get

```
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

as result on system out, but I am no longer able to access any repository with tortoise repo-browser.

Entering svn://localhost/Example in repo-browser leads to a "Can't connect to localhost/connection refused" error.

I cleared every cache in tortoise, checked the firewall settings and rebooted my system. The result stays the same: I can connect from command line and cannot connect from tortoise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer on the web which explains what happend. I made a small mistake when recreating the svn service, what I did not realize, because from command line everything worked well. That was the most irritating thing.

I missed the following option:

```
--listen-host 0.0.0.0
```

Or maybe I used an example which explicitly let svnserve listen to IPv6 only.

After adding the above option to my "sc create" command everything worked fine. It tells svnserve to listen for IPv4 connections, which was missing, so that Tortoise could not connect.

Comment: You should accept this answer (even if it's your own) if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I forgot this over time, because there was a 7 hour barrier before I could accept my own answer.

Comment: I faced the same problem today.

Answer (score 0):

(just a guess, but it might be useful)

Check the versions of your Tortise client and your command line client.  You might find that one or the other is quite out-of-date.  While Subversion servers can support more than one client, sometimes certain features are needed which the client cannot support.  In such a case, the client will not work.

Comment: I didn't change any of the installed software, all versions are the same as before I moved the repository folder. The reinstallation I meant was just the svnserve as a windows service which I think was successful because I can access all my repositories from command line.